# Why is ChessBase calling this a draw?

Tags: chessbase

[image]

The above image is clearly not a draw. Why is ChessBase giving this errant line?

After I play 10...Kd6!! Now White is winning. Why is ChessBase giving this error?

Comment: What is the engine? Is it standard chess or some variant? Maybe you could review some settings...

Comment: It's Deep Fritz 14 @Daniel

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Has the position after 10....Kd6 occurred earlier in this game? If yes, the engine thinks it's a repetition and shows "0.00".

More information on the repetition issue can be found on [this thread on TalkChess](http://talkchess.com/forum3/viewtopic.php?f=2&t=50855&start=40#p552541), a forum dedicated to computer chess.

Comment: Maybe, but the line finishes after f7. Furthermore, OP wrote that he did play ...Kd6 himself on the board in the question. If ...Kd6 was a repetition, OP should have notified by the program.

Comment: The fact that the engine suddenly says that white is winning once 10....Kd6 is played, is a strong indication that it's a classical repetition issue. 10....Kd6 could be the second occurence only. In such a case, as far as I know, it doesn't matter if the line itself is winning or not.

Comment: I'm not saying you're wrong, you could be right! However, the app should have shown a three repetition message if 10...Kd6 was indeed the drawing move. I don't know! We're both guessing!!

Comment: I agree, it's hard to tell!

Comment: @Smallchess it normally does notify me. There is not enough information to answer the question: I should have provided the notation.

Comment: Does the app have a "Setup position" feature? If so, you could try analyzing that position again, with black to move. If the engine says that white is winning, at least we could be certain that it is not a bug.

Answer (score 3):

This is a **bug**. The position should be simple enough for the engine to work out a promotion. You should report the incident to ChessBase.

Comment: I don't think that does anything; I feel they overlook all of these bug reports. I was hoping I would get more publicity here.